# Function that implements Taylor Series in C return the value of the argument

Tags: c, taylor-series

I was experimenting with the Taylor Series expansion for tan(x) in C. I've created a super simple function whose purpose is to return the answer of the expansion (see code below). The issue is that when one invokes it, the answer is the argument of the tangent, i.e. if you call the function tangent as `tangent(0.7853981634)`, which is pi/4 btw, you get that same number 0.7853981634.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float power(float x, int pow);
float tangent(float x);

void main(){
    float ans;
    ans = tangent(0.7853981634);

    printf("La tangente da %f \n", ans);
}

float tangent(float x){
    return x + 1/3 * (x * x * x) + 2/15 * (x * x * x * x * x);
}
```

**NOTE:** I know that there are plenty of things to improve, it's just that I don't know why this code does not work properly.

Comment: Both `1/3` and `2/15` evaluate to zero, because it is an integer division whose result is also an integer. Use a float literal (`1.0f / 3`) or an explicit type cast (`(float) 1 / 3`) to force a floating-point division. (Or, of course, put the division after the floating-point product: `x * x * x / 3`.)

Comment: Thank you M Oehm. Appreciate it!

Comment: Note an answer to the question but a note: Depending on the level of optimization done by the compiler, evaluating (x * x * x) and (x * x * x * x * x) could result in 6 multiplications. If the compiler is not smart enough to optimize it, you should use intermediate variables. To see if the code is optimized, you have to look at the code emitted by the compiler.

Comment: I see your point, the precision is TERRIBLE. For instance, tan(45) = 0.9991711 (and the tan(x) is written up the term with x^9). How could I see "how smart" is gcc, my compiler?

Comment: I told you: "To see if the code is optimized, you have to look at the code emitted by the compiler". You need to understand a minimum of assembly language, enough to count how many multiplication are generated. We have no idea about which compiler you use nor what options you gave. Many compilers have options for optimization. Or you can write two version: the actual one and a second one with intermediate variables and time each one for 1000000 calls. Compare the execution times.